# How does file:// work within a docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, localstack

I'm dockerizing my app that uses AWS live. I'm using localstack locally in my docker container to emulate. I'm almost done, but I'm stuck on setting the cors configuration for the localstack bucket. I'm following the docs for setting cors here: https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/s3/#configuring-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-s3 I'm stuck with this command: `awslocal s3api put-bucket-cors --bucket cors-bucket --cors-configuration file://cors-config.json` Specifically, what does `file://` do and what are its implications in a docker container?

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error parsing parameter '--cors-configuration': Unable to load paramfile file://./cors-config.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './cors-config.json'
```

Currently I have my cors-config.json in the same folder as the .sh script that's calling it, like this:

```
docker 
   aws
     - cors-config.json
     - Dockerfile
     - localstack-script.sh // bash script which calls the put-bucket-cors command
```

Here's my actual localstack-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
awslocal s3api \
create-bucket --bucket super-simple-cms \
--create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-central-1 \
--region eu-central-1
awslocal s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket super-simple-cms --acl public-read
aws s3api put-bucket-cors --bucket super-simple-cms  --cors-configuration file://./cors-config.json
```

Here's the Dockerfile which runs the bash script:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 localstack/localstack:3.0
COPY --chown=localstack ./localstack-script.sh /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/localstack-script.sh
RUN chmod u+x /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/localstack-script.sh
```

As you can see, I'm trying a relative `./` but that's not working. What am I not understanding about `file://`?

Comment: Have you copied the file into the Docker image, i.e. in your `Dockerfile`... `COPY cors-config.json .`

Comment: @Phil I've updated the question, I can try that now

Comment: if the file isn't included in the image, your script when run in the container will hit the error you're seeing because the file simply doesn't exist there

Comment: Yea that was it, I was getting confused because this is a nested Dockerfile and I thought the root Dockerfile would take care of it for some reason. Still learning Docker, thanks.